# How a method or function do same thing when we create two difference object/instance on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, prototype

When I read this [Prototypes in JavaScript article](https://medium.com/better-programming/prototypes-in-javascript-5bba2990e04b)  on internet,I saw this code

```
function Human(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName,
    this.lastName = lastName,
    this.fullName = function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}

var person1 = new Human("Virat", "Kohli");

console.log(person1);
```

when he explains about this, he mentions `"two instances of function fullName that do the same thing."`. I confuse at this point. How this function doing same thing? because this function will be show two difference full name therefore how is it possible to do same thing? any one can help me?

Comment: What the author meant was that the method fullName will return the same properties for every object created

Comment: The biggest problem  is when we create objects each time, we re-create these generic methods like fullname again and again due to that we just wasting memory therefore we use prototype concept, but properties like firstname, lastname also we create again and again when we create objects there are also generic properties for each objects so this also wasting memory. so why are they mention methods are only wasting memory? sorry I am beginner for this concept so I have these type of doubts and my English also not good sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It means the output of fullName will always be firstName + lastName of new object ... So fullName always use same properties of new objects.

Comment: I have some idea from your answer but In Javascript, are the methods completely generic? and what is the mean by "Each of those methods are dynamic"? how is it generic? can u explain?